# remove quotes from string on only numeric values in r

Tags: r

Given the string, how can I get the desired outcome?

```
('9','','','','','','','','31.23','testing7'),('10','','','','','','','','31.23','testing10')
```

Desired Output

```
(9,'','','','','','','',31.23,'testing7'),(10,'','','','','','','',31.23,'testing10')
```

Comment: Probably not at all, ["all elements of an atomic vector must be the same type"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#vectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
s <- "('9','','','','','','','','31.23','testing7'),
      ('10','','','','','','','','31.23','testing10')"

gsub("'(-?\\d+(?:[\\.,]\\d+)?)'", x = s, replacement = "\\1")
```

Regex explanation:

- `'`  match literal single quote character
- `()` capture group
- `?` match between 0-1 times
- `\\d+` match digit 1 and unlimited times
- `\\1` group 1

This should allow for negative numbers and decimals.

**Output**

```
"(9,'','','','','','','',31.23,'testing7'),(10,'','','','','','','',31.23,'testing10')"
```